# Training YOLO/Darknet in other datasets does not detect anything in new test images

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am following the following tutorial

https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

I am trying to firstly use my own dataset. It has annotations in .xml files as the training requires. I also have the labels in txt files. The training goes fine. But, when I use one image that I used in the training just to check if the detector works, it simply detects nothing.

Then, I tried to follow the examples of the website https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ for the VOC dataset. The training again goes well, but, again, nothing is detected.

My command to train:

```
./darknet detector train cfg/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet53.conv.74
```

My command to test:

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg backup/yolov3-voc_final.weights VOCdevkit/VOC2012/JPEGImages/2007_000033.jpg
```

My cfg/voc.data

```
classes= 20
train  = /home/server/Desktop/dataset_others/darknet/train.txt
valid  = /home/server/Desktop/dataset_others/darknet/2007_test.txt
names = /home/server/Desktop/dataset_others/darknet/data/voc.names
backup = /home/server/Desktop/dataset_others/darknet/backup
```

My data/voc.names

```
aeroplane
bicycle
bird
boat
bottle
bus
car
cat
chair
cow
diningtable
dog
horse
motorbike
person
pottedplant
sheep
sofa
train
tvmonitor
```

One thing I noticed in the training is the big amount of nan values as values found during training, as you can see below: [image]

What did I miss when training the network for VOC dataset?

Comment: What is your batch size? Did you change the parameters in the .cfg file?

Comment: @Sharan_Sundar I used the standard .cfg file. Is there something I must change?

Comment: Yes you must modify it for your use case. Starting from the number of classes to the height and width of detections. -nan occurring during training mostly indicates problems with data. Recheck parameters and the data(images and xml files).

Comment: @Sharan_Sundar I will check it and, if it works, I will be glad to mark your answer as the correct one. Thank you. Wait for me.